# DB2 SQL forecast generation based giving as parameters end date

Tags: sql, db2, forecasting

I have a table with activities. The columns are: activityId, nextDate, frequency.
The frequency is in months.
I need a query that will generate all the dates at which the activity will take place based on frequency (in months).
I am using DB2.

Activities table:

| activityId | nextDate | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/01/2024 | 2 |

Giving parameter: 12/31/2024

Output needed:

| activityId | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/01/2024 |
| 1 | 05/01/2024 |
| 1 | 07/01/2024 |
| 1 | 09/01/2024 |
| 1 | 11/01/2024 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a recursive CTE

```
with activities (activityId, nextDate, frequency) as (
  values (1, date '2024-03-01', 2)
),
activities_this_year (activityId, firstDate, number, nextDate, frequency) as (
  select activityId, nextDate as firstDate, 1, nextDate, frequency from activities
  union all
  select
    activityId,
    firstDate,
    number + 1,
    nextDate + frequency month,
    frequency
  from activities_this_year
  where nextDate + frequency month < this_year(current date) + 1 year
)
select activityId, nextDate from activities_this_year order by activityId, nextDate
```

| ACTIVITYID | NEXTDATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-03-01 |
| 1 | 2024-05-01 |
| 1 | 2024-07-01 |
| 1 | 2024-09-01 |
| 1 | 2024-11-01 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Kpx2l1Iy)